# Content Disappears in Landscape Mode - iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to create a new view using AutoLayout in an existing iOS app.

However I'm seeing some behaviour I can't understand, which is that when I preview or view in the simulator in Landscape mode on an iPhone, everything disappears from the view.  Landscape mode in the iPad simulator works as expected

Here's a few screenshots to illustrate:

[image: Storyboard View]
[image: Storyboard Preview]

I can't understand what's happening here and I'm not sure where to begin to debug it.  Has anyone encountered this before, or have any suggestions as to the cause and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - it was the settings at the bottom of the View in Storyboard.  Instead of

```
wAny hAny
```

I had

```
wAny hRegular
```